# Scala provide type information in subclassed generic function

Tags: scala, generics, inheritance

Here is my problem.

I have an abstract class that defines a method with type parameters as input and output. I want the subclasses to provide the type information when subclassing but I want to do it in a way that I don't parametrize the whole class.

Some pseudo code of what I'm aiming at.

```
abstract class A {
  def foo[T](t: T): T
}

class B() extends A {
  override foo[Int](t: Int): Int = t + 1
}

class C() extends A {
  override foo[Double](t: Double): Double = t + 1.0
}
```

How do I pass the type information on subclassing? I looked at similar problems. They address that with self types, type classes and abstract types.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've said, an abstract type on `A` can solve that:

```
abstract class A {
  type T
  def foo(t: T): T
}

class B extends A {
  override type T = Int
  override def foo(t: Int): Int = t + 1
}

class C extends A {
  override type T = Double
  override def foo(t: Double): Double = t + 1.0
}
```

Comment: if I try to work with the foo function from the outside and pass it something like `foo(t)` where t is defined as `T <: A`, I get `type mismatch; expected t.T; actual T`

Comment: What do you mean "pass from the outside"? You need to define the type when creating the instance of `B` and `C`.

Comment: `class D[T <: A] {
  def blah(t: T): T = {
    t.foo(t)
  }
}`

Comment: When calling the `t.foo(t)` I get the type mismatch.

Answer (score 1):

What about "parameterizing" on the abstract Class:

```
abstract class A[T] {
    def foo(t: T): T
}

class B extends A[Int] {
    override def foo(t: Int): Int = t + 1
}

class C extends A[Double] {
    override def foo(t: Double): Double = t + 1.0
}
```

Comment: Sorry but as I said - I don't want to parametrize my class with a Type cause of some subclassing later on.

Comment: Ah OK, fair enough, I missed that (but I fail to see how this can create "subclassing problems")

Answer (score 1):

Your `A` is specifically promising that it can be called with *any* `T`. So any type that extends it must fulfill that promise.

```
val a: A = ...
val x = a.foo("a") // calls foo[String]
val y = a.foo(1) // calls foo[Int]
```

is perfectly good code. But when it's executed, `a` can actually be a `B`, `C`, or anything that extends `A`. So "providing the type information when subclassing" doesn't really make sense: it would completely break the meaning of subtyping (or of type parameters).